# SignalR Core with Angular: Failed to connect. Error: Error during negotiation request

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to use signalR to connect ASP.NET Core API with Angular 5 it work fine in ASP.NET MVC 5 but when move my code to ASP.NET Core it give me this error

> http://localhost:54015/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=.. net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Could not connect
Failed to connect. Error: Error during negotiation request.

//Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSignalR();
   services.AddCors();

   services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   //...
   app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
   app.UseSignalR((options) => {
      options.MapHub<ValuesHub>("/Hubs/Values");
   });

   //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
   app.UseMvc();
}
```

//NotificationHub.cs

```
public class NotificationHub: Hub
{
   public Task Send(string message)
   {
      return Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", message);
   }
}
```

//Angular
//app.module.ts

```
import { SignalRModule } from 'ng2-signalr';
import { SignalRConfiguration } from 'ng2-signalr';

export function createConfig(): SignalRConfiguration {
  const c = new SignalRConfiguration();
  c.hubName = 'Chat';
  c.url = 'http://localhost:49319';
  return c;
}
```

//app.component.ts

```
import { SignalR, BroadcastEventListener } from 'ng2-signalr';
onMessageSent$ = new BroadcastEventListener<string>('Send');
constructor(private _signalR: SignalR) {

}
ngOnInit() {
   this._signalR.connect().then((c) => {
   console.log("success", c)
   c.listen(this.onMessageSent$);
      //do stuff
   })
   .catch(
   (error) => {
      console.log("error", error)
   });
   this.onMessageSent$.subscribe((msg: string) => {
      console.log("msg", msg)
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two errors in your sample code. You seem to want to use a “chat” hub but don’t have a path for. Second the client wants to use port 49319 but the request shown uses port 54015. I’d say check your configuration a little more.